# Asserting POST data in a ZF2 controler test

Tags: php, zend-framework2, phpunit

Here is a PHPUnit test for the implementation of post DATA, for a ZF2 Controler :

```
public function testEditActionPost()
    {
        $this->routeMatch->setParam('action', 'editaffaire');
        $this->routeMatch->setParam('idaffaire', '400');

        $data = array(
            'foo' => 'bar',
            'bar' => 'foo'
        );

        $this->request->setMethod('POST')
                      ->setPost($data);

        $result   = $this->controller->dispatch($this->request);
        $response = $this->controller->getResponse();

        $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
    }
```

But this does not work ... PHPUnit sends me an error :

> 1) MaintenanceTest\Controller\SitesControllerTest::testEditActionPost
>   Argument 1 passed to Zend\Http\Request::setPost() must be an instance
>   of Zend\St dlib\ParametersInterface, array given

Here is my setUp :

```
protected function setUp()
{
    $serviceManager = Bootstrap::getServiceManager();

    $this->controller = new SitesController();

    $this->request    = new Request();
    $this->routeMatch = new RouteMatch(array('controller' => 'index'));
    $this->event      = new MvcEvent();
    $config = $serviceManager->get('Config');
    $routerConfig = isset($config['router']) ? $config['router'] : array();
    $router = HttpRouter::factory($routerConfig);
    $this->event->setRouter($router);
    $this->event->setRouteMatch($this->routeMatch);
    $this->controller->setEvent($this->event);
    $this->controller->setServiceLocator($serviceManager);
}
```

How can I dispatch my test controller ? Thanks !

**Edit - controler code :**

```
public function editaffaireAction()
    {
        try {
            $iMaiAffaireId = $this->params('idaffaire');

            $oAffaire = $this->maiAffaireService->selectByIdOrCreate($iMaiAffaireId);

            $maiAffairesForm = new FMaiAffaireForm(
                $oAffaire
            );

            if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
                $maiAffairesForm->setInputFilter($oAffaire->getInputFilter());
                $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
                $maiAffairesForm->setData($postData);
                if ($maiAffairesForm->isValid()) {
                    $aData = $maiAffairesForm->getData();
                    $oAffaire->exchangeArray($aData);
                    $iMaiAffaireId = $this->maiAffaireService->save($oAffaire);
                }
            }

            $viewModel = new ViewModel([
                'oAffaire'        => $oAffaire
            ]);
            return $viewModel;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Exception($e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters you want to pass to `setPost()` need to be in a `Parameters` object:

```
use Zend\Stdlib\Parameters;   
//...
$this->request->setMethod('POST')
    ->setPost(new Parameters($data));
```

See the documentation of Zend 2:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.test.phpunit.html#testing-your-controllers-and-mvc-applications

Comment: It works but my form can't be valid, it shows "not in array" errors, why ?

Comment: I really don't undernstand ... my value IS in my array, and sent in my request !

Comment: Well since I don't know your controller code, I can't help you with this problem :-)

Comment: Okay I understood. My elements are selects inputs. If I send sample data as my test, this sends me an error "The input was not found in the haystack" , I corrected it with : 'disable_inarray_validator' => true in my select ...